# Detecting if app returns to MainActivity from another activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

Scenario:

- my application refreshes its contents in the `OnStart()` method of
  the MainActivity by downloading some stuff from the internet. I use
  the `OnStart()` as I'd like the contents to be refreshed whenever the
  user opens the application, not just at the `OnCreate()`
- The application has a tablayout and the contents of the different tabs are called as fragments from a ViewPager
- The fragments contain custom ListViews. Clicking to a listitem calls a new activity displaying more information about the given
  item. The OnClickListener is called from the fragment with the
  following code:

:

```
myListView.setOnItemClickListener(
        new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent myNewIntent = new Intent(parent.getContext(), activity_details.class);
                startActivity(myNewIntent);
            }
        });
```

The problem I have is that when the user returns from this newly opened activity by pressing the back button of his phone then my app returns to the MainActivity, the `OnStart()` method is executed again, so the app download stuff again from the internet, which is undesired. (I need a refresh only when the user opens the app)

This means I need some sort of a mechanism to signal that we are returning from a different Activity. I have couple ideas:

1. Using sharedpreferences.
2. Using some sort of a global variable (not a big friend of this idea)
3. Database (ehh... I dont think so)
4. Using the `onActivityResult` in the MainActivity. This sounds ok for the first sight but as I call the new activity from a fragment it separates the actual activity call from where I process the results, therefore complicates the code

Help me out with sharing your ideas.

Comment: If you need to know if this is the second onStart, just use a flag.  Default it to false, set it to true when onStart is called, and check it next time onStart is called.

Comment: @GabeSechan If the exits from the app by pressing the home button and the launches the app again then I need a refresh. But I dont if the user returns from the `activity_details` activity. So a simple flag wont work.

Comment: Hitting home doesn't exit the app.  I suggest you term it "leave" because otherwise you'll confuse yourself.  It seems like you want to be triggering this behavior in onCreate, not onStart from your description.

Comment: Yes, probably leave is a better term. So if the user 'starts' the app then I need a refresh, and also I need a refresh everytime the user restarts ('comes back') the app after 'leaving' it with the home button. On an app restart the OnCreate is not called, so I can't put my refresh routine there.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use an interface, and override `onBackPressed` so it sends to `MainActivity` that "hey i am returning , so don't download anything" via the interface

fragment

```
public class itemFragment extends Fragment {

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public itemFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    public static itemFragment newInstance() {
        return new itemFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item, container, false);
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event


    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        //send true to Main Activity before detaching
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(true);
        mListener = null;
    }


    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {

        void onFragmentInteraction(Boolean iamBack);
    }
}
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements itemFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    boolean backPress = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        //Download whatever you want if backPress is false
        if (!backPress) {

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Boolean backPress) {
        this.backPress = backPress;
    }
}
```

Note : I still didn't try it, so tell me if you face any problem.

Comment: Could you share some code about this? I'm new in both Android and Java, so I'm not sure what do you mean exactly.

Comment: @Istvanb  sure i'll as soon as i can

Comment: thanks for getting back to me with the code. I haven't tried it but I know exactly what do you do here with the interface as - incidentally - I'm implementing the exact same method to communicate between a fragment and my MainActivity. What I dont understand in your code (and also in the one I'm using) is that what does it really mean when you cast your interface instance into Context. The solution works perfectly fine, but I dont understand the concept behind.

Comment: @Istvanb can you tell me which code i am casting my interface into context :/

Comment: ups, its actually the other way, you cast your context to an interface  `mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;` which is a completely different thing. Nonetheless I dont understand what does casting a context to an Interface really mean

Comment: @Istvanb i am afraid to say that neither me :/ maybe if you paste the whole code i can get it

Comment: well it was coming from your code. Its in the onAttach method.

Comment: @Istvanb oh i am sorry , that line checks if the MainActivity implements the interface indeed if so it -MainActivity which is refered to as context- can be cast to that interface , like if you watch some old videos you will notice that they cast the object returned from (findViewWithd) method to the object they want like ... Spinner spin = (Spinner) findViewWithId(R.id.spinner) .. that because spinner actually extends from Object ... i hope you get it :/

Comment: Thanks a lot for explaining it! I understand that it is possible, but is there some sort of a documentation which explains why is it possible? I've just started to learn Java/Android, and I have never thought that a Context can be casted to an interface if the Context implements the interface.

Comment: Have you never made Activity implements OnClickListener then passed your mainactivity as a listener?? Like View.setOnClickListener(tthis) ?

Answer (score 1):

I think using SharedPreferences would be a good solution.  You could set a value in the `onBackPressed()` method in the activity you don't want to trigger the sync code in and then check for it in the `onStart()` method of your MainActivity, and reset the value if it indicates you are returning from a state that you don't want to do a sync.  You may find other states (maybe configuration changes) you would not want to sync on returning from as well and use the same setting.

Comment: Certainly easy to implement (I have already done it). I'm just wondering if this is a solution what another android developer would accept as a good practice or if its not recommended.

Comment: I think the main downside of using SharedPreferences is, in theory at least, performance.  I use SharedPreferences for maintaining "global state" info, because even if you store it in a global on the Application class or in a static singleton the info is lost if your process is killed, and when it restarts it does not pass thru MainActivity, it goes straight to the last viable Activity, with all new values for those globals.

Answer (score 0):

it reads `detecting return from another activity`, which hints for `startActivityForResult()`; this does not complicate anything, while dispatching the event, so that the `Fragment` will get notified:

for the `MainActivity`:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    this.currentFragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

of course, the current `Fragment` also would need to implement `onActivityResult()`:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    ...
}
```

then one can return data from the `DetailActivity`:

```
Intent data = new Intent();
this.setResult(AppCompatActivity.RESULT_OK, data);
this.finish();
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining why do I need the onActivityResult in the fragment as well? I guess that if I call a new Intent from my fragment then once the new Activity is finished it will return to the mainActivity. (When I'm saying its complicating thing I mean that as I call the DetailActivity from a fragment then it could be confusing that I have an OnActivityResult in my MainActivity. But this could be standard procedure, I'm just new in Java and Android)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is an activity variable. Even if you don't like this kind of solution. I don't know what is your architecture but with viewModel it's totally clean. Even without it, it's understandable and easy to maintain.

Like this:

```
private var syncToPerformed: Boolean = true

override fun onKeyDown(keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent?): Boolean {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME) {
        syncToPerformed = true
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event)
}

override fun onCreate() {
    if (syncToPerformed) {
        // DO YOUR SYNCHRONISATION
       syncToPerformed = false
    }
}
```

Also it's not useful to use onStart with this solution.